# What does yellow border around component in KiCad Pcbnew mean?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

I'm working on a PCB layout in KiCad Pbcnew.

I notice there is one and only one component that has a yellow border, R16/10K in the screen shot below.

What does that indicate? It doesn't seem to correlate with the most recently clicked element or anything like that.

[image]

Comment: what layer did you place it on?

Comment: I just added it by importing a netlist. Interestingly, later on the yellow box disappeared. Maybe it's just an artifact that gets cleaned up later or something.

Comment: Yellow typically is the board outline layer. For some reason, it seems to be thinking the courtyard or component outline should be a board outline. First time seeing that. If it ever happens again, try redrawing the screen (F3) or switch the drawing mode temporarily (F9, F11, F12). Usually just a screen redraw will fix any graphics anomaly.

Comment: I tried the screen redraw (Cmd+R, I'm on a Mac) with no success. But I'll try the F9, F11, F12 next time I see it and see what happens, thanks :)

Comment: @scanny changing the renderer is what F11,12 etc does. You should see those options to change the renderer engine used in the top menus somewhere. There is OpenGL, Cairo, and default. At least in my Windows version of KiCAD there is. I use the recent dev builds, not the super old "stable" ones

Answer (score 2):

Looks more like an courtyard outline on the wrong layer - in your setup the faint grey lines are the courtyard (some footprints don't have them, depending on your source and the age of the library you use, or if they are entirely DIY).
For that device the designer might have accidentally put the courtyard onto the same layer as the value of the part.
It's hard to tell as we can't see your layer color choices.

PS: I know this is nearly 24 months old, but it comes up as unanswered.